# too few parameters expected 2

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc, pysimplegui

so im trying to make a question program and having an issue with database server
this is the code:q

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pypyodbc
import random

sg.theme('random')
conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\FUAD\Documents\Database9.accdb;')
main_menu = [
    [sg.Push(),sg.Button('X',key='-exit-')],
    [sg.Text('PROJECT 1',pad=(70,40)) ],
    [sg.Button('Add question',size=(10,3),key=('add_question'))],
    [sg.Button('ask question',size=(10,3),key = ('-AskQuestion-'))],
    [sg.Button('see all the questions',size=(10,3),key='-SeeAllTheQuestions-')]
 ]

window = sg.Window('project',main_menu,no_titlebar=True)
while True:
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cursor.execute('select * from Questions')
 questionslist = cursor.fetchall()
 sg.theme('darkblue')


 def see_all_the_questions(delete, set):
     questions = {}
     for i in questionslist:
         questions[i[1]] = i[0]
     layout = [
         [sg.Text('What you want to do?', key='-text-'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('X', key='-Cancel*SeeQuestions-')],
         [sg.Button('delete', key='-delete-'), sg.Button('set the question', key='-set-'),
          sg.Button('Cancel', key='-cancel-', visible=False)],
         [sg.Listbox([i[1] for i in questionslist], s=(50, 25), key='-listbox-', enable_events=True)]
     ]
     window = sg.Window('Question list', layout)
     while True:
         event, values = window.read()

         if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
             break
         if event == '-delete-':
             delete, set = True, False
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=True)
         if event == '-cancel-':
             delete, set = False, False
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=False)
         if event == '-set-':
             delete, set = False, True
             window['-cancel-'].update(visible=True)
         if event == '-listbox-' and delete == True:
             cursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM Questions WHERE ID in ({questions[values[event][0]]})')
             cursor.commit()

         **def set_question():

             sg.theme('darkbrown')
             set_layout = [
                 [sg.Text('enter the question to be changed'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('X', key='-SetQuestionExit-')],
                 [sg.Input(key='-Input-'), sg.Button('Enter', key='EnterSetQuestion')]
             ]
             window = sg.Window("", set_layout)
             while True:
                 event, values = window.read()
                 if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                     break
                 tuple = [values["-Input-"]]
                 window.close()
                 return tuple
         if event == '-listbox-' and set == True:
            print(f'event {values[event][0]}')
            willchange = set_question()
            new_dictionary = {}
            cursor.execute('select * from Questions')
            new_question_list = cursor.fetchall()
            for i in new_question_list:
                new_dictionary[i[1]] = i[0]
            print(f'newdictionary {new_dictionary}')
            questions = new_dictionary
            print(f'questions {questions}')
            print(f'willchangeid {questions[values[event][0]]} willchange  {willchange}')
            cursor.execute(f'UPDATE Questions SET  Question_field = ? WHERE id = {questions[values[event][0]]}', willchange)
            cursor.commit()
            set = False
            window['-cancel-'].update(visible = False)**

 def add_question(question):
     sg.theme('darkbrown')
     layout = [
         [sg.Text('please enter your question'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('X', key='-Exit-')],
         [sg.Input(key='-input-'), sg.Button('-Enter-')],
         [sg.Text('Your question successfully added to questions!', key='sccful', visible=False)]
     ]
     window = sg.Window('question adder', layout, no_titlebar=True)
     while True:
         event, values = window.read()
         print(questionslist)
         if event == '-Exit-':
             window.close()
             break
         if event == '-Enter-' and values['-input-']!='':
             print(questionslist)
             print(questionslist[-1:][0])
             question = (questionslist[-1:][0][0]+1,values['-input-'])
             cursor.execute('''
                         INSERT INTO Questions VALUES(?,?)''',question)
             cursor.commit()
             window.close()

 event,values = window.read()
 if event == '-exit-':
     window.close()
     break
 if event == '-SeeAllTheQuestions-':
     see_all_the_questions(False,False)
 if event == 'add_question':
     add_question('')
```

so pay attention to see_all_the_questions(delete, set) part you can see in that part i can delete and set elements what i want to do is set the elements but i can't. in

```
if event == '-listbox-' and set == True:
```

part i'm using set_question() function and get input from user and all the questions are in the "questions" dictionary in questions dictionary all data's keys are access's IDs in this part

```
cursor.execute(f'UPDATE Questions SET  Question_field = ? WHERE id = {questions[values[event][0]]}', willchange)
```

i give id with questions and give the data to  be changed this code works pretty well in first time but in second time it gave me error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/FUAD/Desktop/Project Final.py", line 112, in <module>
    see_all_the_questions(False,False)
  File "C:/Users/FUAD/Desktop/Project Final.py", line 79, in see_all_the_questions
    cursor.execute(f'UPDATE Questions SET  Question_field = ? WHERE id = {questions[values[event][0]]}', willchange)
  File "C:\Users\FUAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1617, in execute
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Users\FUAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\FUAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 987, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.')
```

i tried to set an element twice and expect to happen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you supply an error message in your question, please supply the entire output of your code, including the stack dump that accompanied the description of the error.  The stack dump will often be of more value than the error message itself.

Comment: this is the whole output                                                                                 event trt
newdictionary {'rauf': 1, 'trt': 2, 'вдмьлвм': 3, 'ilyai': 4}
questions {'rauf': 1, 'trt': 2, 'вдмьлвм': 3, 'ilyai': 4}
willchangeid 2 willchange  ['changed']
event ilyai
newdictionary {'rauf': 1, 'changed': 2, 'вдмьлвм': 3, 'ilyai': 4}
questions {'rauf': 1, 'changed': 2, 'вдмьлвм': 3, 'ilyai': 4}
willchangeid 4 willchange  ['something']                                                         in here "event" is where i clicked in and i edit the error code

Comment: I know nothing about Python, but the error message typically tells that a table or a field name or a parameter is either misspelled or missing. So, double-check your code and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is indeed in this line, but we do not have enough information about it to debug, however I think you are suffering from code injection, specifically a bind parameter placeholder injection.

```py
cursor.execute(
    f'UPDATE Questions SET Question_field = ? WHERE id = {questions[values[event][0]]}',
    willchange
)
```

Just looking at your query, you're working with questions, and questions tend to contain interrogation marks. With your f-string the inserted value will not be escaped.

If the question `Where is Brian ?` is inserted in your f-string, you would execute:

```py
cursor.execute(
    'UPDATE Questions SET Question_field = ? WHERE id = Where is Brian ?',
    willchange
)
```

Which is missing a parameter for its second `?` and would raise `Too few parameters. Expected 2.`.

This is pretty innocuous, but a SQL injection like `NULL; DROP TABLE Questions; --` would make you execute the following, which would drop the table you need, bricking your application.

```py
cursor.execute(
    'UPDATE Questions SET Question_field = ? WHERE id = NULL; DROP TABLE Questions; --',
    willchange
)
```

So, remember not use string templating or concatenation for SQL queries with user input, rather, use bind parameters (if you control the inserted string templating is acceptable).

```py
cursor.execute(
    f'UPDATE Questions SET Question_field = ? WHERE id = ?',
    (willchange, questions[values[event][0]])
)
```

Comment: "**NEVER** use string templating or concatenation for SQL queries", except when you have to. For example, `cursor.execute("UPDATE ? SET …", "Questions")` won't work.

Comment: @GordThompson ok yes, that was a bit extreme there, I'll tone down to `with values you do not control`.